# Where can I download the Microsoft windows OCR language package files?

Tags: uwp, ocr

I'm developing an UWP app, I want to use the Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine to extract text from an image. On my working machine it only support English language and I want to extract Chinese word, I know I can install the OCR and Handwriting language packages by add a new language. But it's seems I can't download them on my working machine.

And I also try to use powershell to install it, but still failed and got the error code = 0x800f0954.

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -name Language.OCR~~~zh-HK~0.0.1.0
```

So I want to know if is possible I can download them from a public linkage?
The packages as bellow:

Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-OCR-zh-hk-Package.cab

Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-OCR-zh-cn-Package.cab

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: See also: [Language and region Features on Demand (FOD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-language-fod)

Answer (score 0):

Your PowerShell command completes nicely for me:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -name Language.OCR~~~zh-HK~0.0.1.0
```

[image]
It needs to be run as Administrator.

---

You can also try this (from [here](https://medium.com/dataseries/using-windows-10-built-in-ocr-with-c-b5ca8665a14e)):

```
$Capability = Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like 'Language.OCR*zh-HK*' }
$Result = $Capability | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
if ($Result.RestartNeeded -eq $True) { Restart-Computer -Force }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems I don't have admin right to execute the PowerShell command on that device.